# Tense of embedded clause in conditional sentences

Tags: sentence-construction, conditionals

"If it were that he **is/were** going out the manager would certainly ask some questions."

I am confused in which tense is used in subordinate clauses of these unreal type sentences. As past tense is used to show the unreal scenario so does it mean that the embedded clause also have to be in the same past tense?

Answer (score 0):

The construction "*If it were that*" is unusual and awkward. The example sentence could be better worded as simply:

> If he were going out the manager would certainly ask some questions.

There is no need to have a subordinate clause here at all, and it makes things less clear and less natural.

Comment: Yeah it's true that the construction sounds quite unnatural but I made it specifically in such way to get an answer of that particular question. My question is about the selection of tense in subordinate clause. I wish I could have come up with a better sentence. Would you please try giving an answer again

Comment: @RADS If I can think of a better example, I will add to the answer. The general rule is that the tense in a subordinate clause may, but need not, match the tense in the main clause.